# Why do various iCloud services on my iPad refuse to stay on?

Tags: ipad, icloud

Every time I turn on various iCloud services on my iPad mini (iOS 7.0.4) including iCloud Backup, Photos, Documents, and Find My iPhone, after sometime the settings would go back to "off." I have no clue why this happens.

Checking the timestamp on my most recent iCloud Backup, I see that the backup runs successfully at some point before the setting goes back to off.

Comment: Is the device jailbroken?

Comment: It is not. Icloud magically started working after trying and retrying. Cant explain it